# Variable scope in a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function(){
"use strict";

var FileCrop = function() {
    this.init();
};

var p = FileCrop.prototype = lx.BaseClass.extend(lx.BaseClass);
p.BaseClass_init = p.init;


p.test = 'test';

p.init = function() {
    // Super
    this.BaseClass_init();
    // Init
    this.ready();

};

p.ready = function() {

    this._initEvents();

};
p._initEvents = function() {
    console.log(this.test); //this works

    this.cropBox.on('mousedown', this.mouseDown);
    $(document).on('mouseup', this.mouseUp);

};

p.mouseDown = function(e) {

console.log(this.test);//this is undefined
    $(document).on('mousemove', this.mouseMove);


};

 p.mouseMove = function(e) {
     console.log('mouse is moving'); //this is never called
 };


lx.FileCrop = FileCrop;
}(window));
```

I'm having trouble with scope and my class.

It would be great if someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to get the test variable throughout the class (in the real class its something else but this gives an easy to understand example).

I have commented on the code above where the test var logs ok and where it doesn't. I'm also having trouble with mouse move. This fails:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', this.mouseMove);
```

Whereas this works:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', p.mouseMove);
```

I was just wondering why this is the case as I am able to use 'this' on mouse down and it works.

Comment: Also, since you have the variable, why not `p.mouseMove`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly ensure that the value of `this` to be used inside your event handlers is a reference to your object. That does not happen automatically when you use an expression like `this.mouseDown`. That gets you a reference to the function, but the relationship to the object referenced by `this` is not preserved.

A simple way to do that in modern JavaScript environments is

```
  this.cropBox.on('mousedown', this.mouseDown.bind(this));
```

The `.bind()` function returns another function, one which will call the originally desired function (your "mouseDown" function) with the value of `this` guaranteed to be what you request via the parameter.

Comment: So basically before, on mouse down, it did not have a reference to my class, but now it does, so it can access all my class vars?

Comment: The key thing is that the value of `this` in a function depends only on how the function is invoked.